# First time using an API. Trying to log in but using jquery/ajax instead of python. The original API is Python. How do I do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

The API I'm trying to use is found here: https://docs.juungle.net/

I already have an account with the web site.

I'm trying to authenticate: https://docs.juungle.net/2-endpoints/authentication.html

As you can see, the code shows a curl:

```
curl -X POST https://www.juungle.net/api/v1/user/login \
  --data '{
    "username": "my-username",
    "password": "my-password"
  }'
```

I've tried the following attempts to convert it to jquery and ajax:

```
var credentials = '{"email": "email","password":"password"}';
 
 
function login()
{
    $.getJSON("https://www.juungle.net/api/v1/user/login", credentials, function(data)
    {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
}
```

```
var credentials = '{"email": "email","password":"password"}';
 
 
function login()
{
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: "https://www.juungle.net/api/v1/user/login",
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: credentials,
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function()
            {
                alert("Cannot login.");
            }
        })
}
```

The first snippet nets me a 404 message, while the second gets me a 422 error code.  If I run the curl with my real credentials from within the API website, it returns my jwt, but I need to be able to integrate this into my JavaScript application.  What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: I also tried the following code:

```
var credentials = '{"email": "my-email","password":"my-password"}';

function login()
{
var url = "https://www.juungle.net/api/v1/user/login";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
console.log(xhr.status);
console.log(xhr.responseText);
           }};

var data = credentials;

xhr.send(data);

}
```

Sadly, even after using my actual email and password, it threw a 422 error with this response:

```
{"email":{"message":"The email field is mandatory.","rule":"required"},"password":{"message":"The password field is mandatory.","rule":"required"}}
```

Edit: Fixed a confusing part of the code where I put things in brackets that didn't cause any problems other than confuse readers.

Comment: For the first snippet, `$.getJSON` will send a GET request to the server while you need a POST. So it's normal that you get 404. In the second snippet, why do you change from `"email": "email"` to  `"email": "[email]"` ?

Comment: It was edited just to show that it was supposed to be replaced, while the email on the left isn't. Didn't mean for it to be confusing.

Comment: For the second snippet, can you add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` into the ajax option ?

Comment: Although I found a solution I will try that for the heck of it.

Comment: That totally worked! Thank you! I added it to my solution as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

The final code that ended up working was only a slight modification of the last code example I posted in one of my edits to the question. It was the content type:

```
var credentials = '{"email": "my-email","password":"my-password"}';


function login()
{   
        var url = "https://www.juungle.net/api/v1/user/login";

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", url);
        
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
           if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
              console.log(xhr.status);
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
           }};
        
        var data = credentials;
        
        xhr.send(data);
        
}
```

Edit: This code also works! Thanks to user:15527686 Đăng-khoa-Đinh for your help!

```
var credentials = '{"email": "my-email","password":"my-password"}';


function login()
{                  
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: "https://www.juungle.net/api/v1/user/login",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            charset: "utf-8",
            datatype: 'json',
            data: credentials,
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function()
            {
                alert("Cannot login.");
            }
        })
        
        
}
```